# Display text with icon in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

How to display text with icon in button? I am using font awesome icons and displaying them using their uni code. Like this:

Now if i add unicode with text the icon doesnt show although text still shows.

This only shows text and Cross instead of icon.

Comment: use SourceSansPro-Light.otf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font awsome is a font, so it can't be in the same block as other text. We need 2 blocks so you can control the font for each of them.

Comment: Hmm i guess that's one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Iconize for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/jsmarcus/Iconize). It let's you use font awesome and other icon fonts too.

Answer (score 1):

you use hex "&#x" instead of "\u"

eg.

```
<Button Text="&#x2699;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms9Patch has an ImageButton and MaterialButton that does a great job of making this easy.

Comment: Forms9Patch ImageButton and MaterialButton has been deprecated.  This function is now standard on Forms9Patch.Button.